# Java Multicast Time To Live is always 0

Tags: java, oracle, sockets, multicast, ttl

I have a problem with setting the TTL on my Datagram packets.  I am calling the setTTL(...) method on the packet before sending the packet to the multicastSocket but if I capture the packet with ethereal the TTL field is always set to 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you have to set an special system property telling the JVM to use an IPv4 stack:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement pfranza's fix in Oracle, where you don't have a command line:

Set the property `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in each Oracle session as follows before calling the java code containing the multicast call with the following PL/SQL snippet:

```
ret := dbms_java.set_property('java.net.preferIPv4Stack','true');
```

If the call is successful it will return NULL.