# Java control IP TTL?

Tags: java, sockets

In Java, is there a way to control the TTL of the IP header for packets sent on a socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently only on Multicast sockets, which have:

```
MulticastSocket.setTimeToLive(int ttl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the TTL using

```
MulticastSocket.setTimeToLive(int ttl);
```

is only going to work if you have enabled the IPV4Stack as outlined by this other question

[Java Multicast Time To Live is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139909/java-multicast-time-to-live-is-always-0)

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```