# Why would my java program send multicast packets with a TTL of 1?

Tags: java, sockets, multicast, ttl

I have a java client program that uses mdns with service discovery to find its associated server.  After much testing on a single network with Windows, Fedora 10, and Ubuntu 8.10, we delivered a test build to a customer.  They report that the client and server never connect.  They sent us a wireshark capture that shows the mdns packets have a TTL of 1 even though our code sets it to 32.  When we test locally, the TTL is 32 just like we set it.  The customer is using Redhat Enterprise 5.

I saw [Java Multicast Time To Live is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139909/java-multicast-time-to-live-is-always-0) but it leaves me curious as to why that question asker has a TTL of 0, but mine is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check out the answer to [Java Multicast Time To Live is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139909/java-multicast-time-to-live-is-always-0)?  This may fix your problem as well.  The answer there references the answerer's [blog entry](http://www.peterfranza.com/2008/09/25/setting-multicast-time-to-live-in-java/).

Comment: I did see that question and answer.  I guess I should add this to the question, but what makes it 1 here but 0 for that guy.

Comment: No idea.  Different kernel versions?  Different IP stack releases or patches?  Different Java release or implementation?  Do let us know if the answer to that post solves your problem.

Comment: I'd still like to know why its a 1 instead of 0, but the answer to how to make it not be that way is the same.